# Can't load map with custom styling with @react-google-maps/api

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, react-google-maps-api

I am using @react-google-maps/api and I have a custom map style. I have a map that uses the style, then I try to load it like this:

```js
const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY;
const MAP_ID = process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_MAP_ID;

const Map = () => {
    const { isLoaded } = useJsApiLoader({
        id: 'google-map-script',
        googleMapsApiKey: API_KEY,
        mapIds: [MAP_ID],
    });

    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <GoogleMap />
        </Wrapper>
   )
};

ReactDOM.render(<Map/>,document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-google-maps-api@1.0.8/lib/index.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```

But the styles don't load, and I don't get any error messages from the JS, neither in the network tab. Am I missing a step, and how can I check if my map is the one being loaded

Note: The account has billing enabled and a credit card added so this is not caused by development only restrictions

Comment: Do **not** post images of code. Instead, provide a [mcve] in the question itself. Please read [ask].

Comment: @MrUpsidown I added the the snippet, but I can't give the keys to the account as it is not personal. I am looking for directions how to investigate whether the map is loading and if it is loading the styles

Comment: I can't tell. It's still not reproducible. And according to the docs, `useJsApiLoader` does not have a `mapId` prop...

Comment: My bad. It takes `mapIds`. It doesn't fix the problem. I actually passed it with `mapIds` initially and tested with mapId and forgot to change it back. The styles still don't load

Comment: Have you tried passing the `mapId` as a `<GoogleMap>` option?

Comment: Yes, It doesn't work

Comment: It [works for me](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-4c7md1?file=index.tsx).

Comment: I saw the problem. When you said `Have you tried passing the mapId as a <GoogleMap> option?` I thought you mean prop, now I added it as `option` prop and it worked. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that it has to be passed as a option to the GoogleMap component like that

```
<GoogleMap
    options={{ mapId: MAP_ID }}
>
```

Thanks @MrUpsidown, for proposing this solution